# Which class logs the error "The element type "XXXXX" must be terminated by the matching end-tag"?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags, parseexception, servletexception

I want t ofind out which class actually  writes the message "The element type "XXXXX" must be terminated by the matching end-tag" to the logs in case end tag is missing in a JSP.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure it depends on the server you are using...

Comment: @piet.t:  am using Tomcat 6. Can you tell which jar/java is responsible for logging this message. Can this message be changed ?